# How Do I Programmatically Get Caller ID on Current Call with Five9?

Tags: crm, phone-call, five9

The docs appear clear as mud on this. I'm building a custom CRM and need a way to get the phone number (caller ID) of the current incoming call. The workstation has the Five9 application installed and the Desktop Toolkit. Now what do I do in the web browser to get that information? My idea was that I'd have a search form and one could click a button called "Search by Caller ID". The web browser would then connect somehow to Five9, get the current phone number of the current call, and send it back to the web server to show records that matched that phone number.

Comment: I believe the technique is to use Five9's CTI API. CTI stands for Computer Telephony Integration. In Javascript, the workstation connects to some XML services called CTI that are hosted locally on the call taker's PC on an alternative port. I'd like to see how this is done in jQuery, but have no examples.

Comment: This jQuery seems to be a step in the right direction: https://github.com/Five9DeveloperProgram/Five9CTISample/blob/master/index.htm